# HOW TO FIX type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to put `buildProfileHeader()` inside the `children` of a `ListView`, I get the error `type Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Widget`

```
@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: cabecera(context, titleText: "Perfil"),
  body: ListView(
    children: [buildProfileHeader()],
  ),
);}}
```

Here's the code for the buildProfileHeader

```
buildProfileHeader() async {
return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: usersRef.doc(widget.profileId).get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return cargandoCircular();
      }
      User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 40.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  backgroundImage:
                      CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          buildCountColumn("publicaciones", 0),
                          buildCountColumn("seguidores", 0),
                          buildCountColumn("siguiendo", 0),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          buildProfileButton(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
              child: Text(
                user.username,
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
              child: Text(
                user.displayName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
              child: Text(
                user.bio,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });}
```

Comment: can you try with removing `async ` from `buildProfileHeader() `, you need to pass widget, 
`FutureBuilder` can handle rest of thing I belive.

Answer (score 0):

`children` expects a list of `Widget`s. What you're doing here with `buildProfileHeader` is that you've marked it as `async`, which means it will return a `Future` value instead.

It doesn't seem like you actually need this function itself to be `async`, so just go ahead and remove that from the method signature

```
buildProfileHeader() {
  return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: usersRef.doc(widget.profileId).get(),
    // ...
```